# How to generate the sha256 hash of a phpmailer generated and sent mail

Tags: hash, phpmailer, send, sha256

is there a way to generate a SHA256 hash of a mail generated and sent via Phpmailer plugin or maybe a method for saving the sent mail in an eml file in a host folder?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by saving the generated mail in this way:

**$mail->preSend();**

**file_put_contents('namethefile.eml', $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());**

Comment: This is as close as you can get on the client end. Bear in mind it will be missing `Return-path` and `Received` headers that you might want to confirm that it was actually sent. I presume you're doing this for some compliance reason? If so, a better way would be to make the mail server save copies of everything; look at things like Enkive and the `always_bcc` option in postfix.